# Timing chain of a mercedes benz

Tags: mercedes-benz

*Does the valves bend when the timing chain slips on sprokets, on a mercedes benz 2008   model C200 komp?*

Comment: Don't know the car specifically, but in 90% of cars, if a timing belt or chain slips, the piston bangs into the valve and bends it.

Comment: FYI, what you want to know is if your car has a free-running  or interference engine. An interference engine out of time will damage the valve(s) and/or cylinder head(s).

Comment: As the answers say, yes. Alternatively I've seen pictures of valves having punched a hole in the piston instead. In any case a significant timing error will cause a collision and engine damage. I can't recall if the K engine there is one of the sensitive ones that "stretch" chains or eat their cam sprockets quickly.

Answer (score 3):

I've checked a number of sources and they all state that the engines in these are [Interference Engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_engine) so there is a good chance of contact between the valves and the piston crowns.  A compression test once the timing has been re-set would be a simple way to check if this has happened without taking the engine to pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can bend valves and mercedes will generally not cover resultant damage even during
warranty period.Mercedessource is a good site hosted by a Mercedes technician